# Suggested tag wiki edit lost edit reason once approved?

Tags: bug, suggested-edits, tag-wiki

I recently [suggested an edit for a tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/204684). When it was approved, the edit reason in the yellow box disappeared on the suggested edit page, although it still shows in the [permalink revision page](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/9346558/2) and the [edit history for the tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/9346558/revisions).

[image: There's no edit reason!]

Just to clarify, the reason *did* show in that yellow box before the edit got approved.

---

**Also, just a side-note:** why are we not allowed to add some message when creating a tag wiki? The "adding # characters in body" message is kind of ambiguous and a tad misleading. Could it not at least say "created tag wiki with # characters" or something more descriptive? My friend was actually confused by that message since he's not as experienced in SO's workings. He thought the page was just a joke and I had to explain to him that it's just how it gets handled.

Comment: Regarding your side note: do you not see a box labeled "edit summary" below the tag wiki edit box? I do.

Comment: @Michael: Nope. When I edit a tag wiki that doesn't exist yet, there is no edit summary box. Only if the tag wiki already exists.